# How do I save a password to my Google account when using Google Chrome on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-management, password-protection

A human end-user can type a user-name and password into a website.

Afterwards, the button to save the password to my Google account goes off the bottom edge of the screen.

How do I save my password? Hiding the Windows task bar and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd>  to zoom out all of the way does not work.

The window has no scroll-bar and is not re-sizable. I cannot click on the corner to re-size the window or scroll up and down.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning down the display scaling? https://winaero.com/how-to-change-dpi-display-scaling-in-windows-11/

Comment: Have you tried scrolling the page down.